# How to set memsql max_pooled_connections

Tags: singlestore

I am using the memory database MemSQL (community version), and I am trying to increase the `max_pooled_connections` settings. I tried two ways:

1) In `/var/lib/memsql/memsql.cnf`, set `max_pooled_connections = 2048`

After restart MemSQL, is still the old setting value 1024

2) `memsql> SET GLOBAL max_pooled_connections = 2048`

The result was

> ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'max_pooled_connections' is a read only variable

Could anyone please kindly let me know how to set this value in MemSQL?

Comment: Hi @eklhad, Sorry I used your method but it keeps showing an error message: Could not reach local agent at 127.0.0.1:9000

Comment: My memsql.cnf settings:
[server]
basedir = .
connect_timeout = 20
core_file
durability = on
lc_messages_dir = ./share
lock_wait_timeout = 60
max_connections = 100000
max_pooled_connections = 2048
maximum_memory = 24576
snapshot_trigger_size = 256m
socket = memsql.sock
tmpdir = .
transaction_buffer = 128m
wait_timeout = 300

port = 3307

Answer (score 3):

By default, MemSQL Ops manages the configuration for your MemSQL cluster. The recommended way to update this value is [documented here](http://docs.memsql.com/latest/ops/cli/MEMSQL-UPDATE-CONFIG/?highlight=config). You will need to make the configuration updates on each node. A quick snippet that would accomplish this would look like this:

```
$ memsql-ops memsql-list -q | xargs -n 1 memsql-ops memsql-update-config --key max_pooled_connections --value 2048
```

--edit: "./memsql-ops" -> "memsql-ops"

Comment: Hi eklad, sorry I used the command but it keeps generating an error message: "Could not reach local agent at 127.0.0.1:9000". Do you have any idea how to get rid of this and make your command work?

Comment: Hey @Sai, did you install using MemSQL Ops? Is MemSQL Ops running on that node? `ps aux | grep memsql-ops` will reveal this for us.

Comment: Yes, the result shows: /var/lib/memsql-ops/lib/memsql-ops start,   /memsqld --defaults-file=.... --pid-file... --user=memsql